# Client certificate authentication with Reverse Proxy

Tags: iis, ssl, reverse-proxy, mutual-authentication

I use SSL mutual authentication for my client and server. Now I would like to add a Reverse Proxy. As far as I understand a Reverse Proxy can't forward a client certificate to the backend web-server. Can I work around this shortcoming? E.g. can my Reverse Proxy send client-information to my backend web-server in order to let my server know what certificate the client is using?

I use IIS 7.5.